# LibGDX - how delete files from ANDROID device after the assignment in Gdx.audio.newMusic();

Tags: android, libgdx, delete-file

Yes, i can't **delete** this file from the **Android device** just because it was assigned to *Gdx.audio.newMusic()*

If i want to delete the file, generally i can do it safely, but if i assign it via *Gdx.audio.newMusic()* then i can no longer delete it.

---

(this is the piece of code working 100%)

```
public class TEST_Android
{
    public static Music M = null;

    // *** Test: Delete-file WITHOUT assignment ***
    //
    public void TEST_A()
    {
        Gdx.files.local("PurpleRain.ogg").delete();                // work 100%
        //
        // --- i've checked the file on Android mobile and is NOT present
        // --- has been deleted correctly
    }



    // *** Test: Delete-file AFTER assignment ***
    //
    public void TEST_B()
    {
        M = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.local("PurpleRain.ogg")); // work 100%
        M.play();                                                  // work 100%
        M.stop();                                                  // work 100%

        M.delete();                                                // doesn't work!
        //
        // --- i've checked the file on Android mobile and is ever present!
        // --- not deleted...
    }
}
```

---

- **Aim** - i need to delete the file after assignment(in some way)

---

- **Question** - how can i delete the file after assigning it to *Gdx.audio.newMusic()*? Eventually if i had to disconnect it how should i do?

---

*Could you help me please? Thank you all*

Answer (score 2):

The [Music](https://static.javadoc.io/com.badlogicgames.gdx/gdx/1.9.9/com/badlogic/gdx/audio/Music.html) class does not have a delete method so obviously you can not call that. You can try calling its `#dispose` Method and try deleting it via `Gdx.files.local("PurpleRain.ogg").delete();` which may, or may not work.

This seems like a strange thing to do however, are you sure you need to delete the file?